# Cannot edit new View

Tags: views, 8

Since I updated to 8.6.10, I can no longer edit a new view. I can create a view but  when I go to the main interface after clicking Save & Edit, nothings works. No matter what I click on, aside from the brief display of turning wheel, nothing happens.

I have checked the log and no error messages and strangely, existing views are working well.

**Update:**
Error message from DevTool console shown below
[image]

Comment: Are you using a contributed theme for administration? Have you checked the developer tools console for errors? This open issue at d.o. looks similar: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2988699 It might be helpful to report your problem there.

Comment: The open issue is exactly same as mine. I'll report my problem there too. Thanks. I've now added the error message from DevTool console.

Comment: No problem! It may also be helpful to include which version you were updating *from*.

Answer (score 0):

If the views are working but you cannot edit, then could something wrong with the views_ui module.

There are two differend modules:

- Views: for views functionality
- Views_ui: for changing views with the web browser at admin section.

Views do not need the Views-ui module activated. This is only for changing existing views. Therefore you can try to deactivate views_ui module and reinstall it.

(Cache clearing is always a good idea, but I think this have you done.)

Comment: Thanks James. Uninstalled & reinstalled Views UI with no luck. I can edit existing Views, my problem is I can't edit any new view I create. And yes, I did clear all cache.